# Angular Error on `ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points`

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular9, angular-cli-v9

I've recently updated my Angular project from 8 to 9. It worked fine on my machine. I tried copying the files and assembling them on another device. While doing npm install I am getting the following error.

I tried removing package.lock.json and removing the node_modules folder completely and tried many times. But nothing works[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution? I'm stuck on same problem

Comment: remove node_modules folder and try installing your dependencies with yarn instead of npm.

Comment: Have you tried removing the ```--create-ivy-entry-points``` flag? The docs at https://angular.io/guide/ivy say: "Don't use --create-ivy-entry-points as this will cause Node not to resolve the Ivy version of the packages correctly."

Comment: Found a solution for this?

Comment: I have same problem upgrading from Angular 9 to 10 .. Seems like my package.json had a script "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points" .. this is run everytime 'npm install' is run. This can be modified to possibly fix whatever problem it is.

Answer (score 0):

1. open Powershell as Administrator
2. cd **yourProjectPath**
3. npm i
4. ng serve